# Generate MSI as part of TFS build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, installation

I want to create MSI build package as part of a TFS build.

What options there are?

**i know about:**

1. install VS on TFS server  (http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/05/14/building-visual-studio-setup-projects-with-tfs-2010-team-build.aspx)
2. Use 3rd party software on tfs

I do not wish to rely on 3rd party software or install vs 2010 on server as i have no licence to spare

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wix: http://wix.sourceforge.net/

It can be invoked using MsBuild. 
I am using it quite successfully in one of my projects

This page gives some info on what is needed http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/authoring_first_msbuild_project.htm

Comment: +1 for wix, visual studio setup projects are a dead end as they won't be included in the next verion of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You should create the MSI Build package on TFS Build the same way you do it locally.

If you don't have anything yet, I strongly encourage you to look at Wix and use it. However Wix is mainly lowlevel package generation for MSI.

If you have complex needs for installation wizard you may rely on InstallShield to get the job done.
By using InstallShield (IS) you have two options:

1. Create a deployment project that will be 100% compatible with Windows Installer (the technology that builds .msi), no more no less. By doing that you can build your IS project pretty easily with Team Build.
2. Create a deployment project with the IS flavor (with a installation bootstrap) and you'll have to deploy the needed runtimes of IS in order to successfully build.

However I strongly encourage you to not choose the way you'll create your deployment package based on the Continous Integration constraints, if you have to install 3rd parties on your build agent, so be it, it won't be the toughest thing to do. (especially if those are VM you can clone)